# How can I centralize cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm looking to have a single `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method that all `UITableView'`s will use for formatting, etc.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Right now I'm thinking I could use a separate class or put delegate methods in my app delegate and hook the `UITableView`'s file's owner to that. But then I'd have to provide those classes/methods access to the data that would normally otherwise be right in the ViewController subclass.

How have others accomplished this sort of thing?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm not looking for a way to return a common cell itself, but rather a way to have a single `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in my entire app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to centralize all of the formatting but have the data sources separate in each class you could create a factory class for your table view cells which provides a method

```
+ (UITableViewCell* ) tableViewCellForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView withType:(int)type;
```

By creating type costants which get passed in, you can create a set of basic table view cells that can then be returned by this class. It is important to pass in the tableView to make use of reusable cells. A `cellForRowAtIndexPath` could now fetch cells from there and configure them depending on the data

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [MyCellFactory tableViewCellForTableView:tableView withType:kMyTypePlain];

    cell.textLabel.text = ....;
}
```

Comment: I'm not looking to centralize the getting of the cells, I'm looking to centralize the entire method. I want the code such as `cell.textLabel.text = ....;` to be in one place, and not have to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in each ViewController.

Comment: Then you definitely have to give that central method access to all data. This may be doable if you can find a "generic" data representation equal to all table views such that the central method does not care about the source of data as long as the data is in the right format. I suppose one has to be design this carefully as it is easy to create a construct that makes the code more complicated than a set of separate methods.

Comment: Right, so how do I implement this 'central' method, specifically?

Comment: Paul.s' comment has the right addition to this. The design of the common data object would strongly depend on how your data looks like and what exactly you want to display. You might create a generic data class that contains one property for every text, color, image etc. that needs to be created. You could then create a generic data source that is initialized using an array of these data objects. The generic data source now would have all information to create the cells on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using an [objective-c category](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) on your ViewController which implements the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

If you're doing something very complex in this method however, I suggest you just create a nib file which contains your cell and then load it in `cellFoRowAtIndexPath`. You could even create a class that inherits from  `UITableViewCell` and stick your own methods/properties in there. I highly recommend this approach.

You can load the nib, say "MyCustomTableCell.nib" which contains your customised `UITableViewCell` like so:

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomTableCell" 
                                                         owner:self
                                                       options:nil];
MyCustomTableCell* cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the answer from @TriPhoenix for most of this.

The only additional thing I would add is that you could potentially send the data along with the call to the factory.

```
[MyCellFactory cellForTableView:tableView withType:kMyTypePlain data:data];
```

You would of course have to ensure that the `data` responds to a common interface to ensure that you can set things easily e.g. making sure each object responds to a similar method like

```
cell.textLabel.text = data.textLabelText;
```

You could do this using a protocol if you like. It's up to you how you structure your data.